# Retrieving http response headers information from any website

Tags: vue.js, http, axios, cors, httpresponse

I'm using **Vue CLI** and **axios**.

I have a searchbar where the user can input (potentially) **any** website and **read info about the HTTP request and response.**

Some of the information I need to get are: *HTTP protocol, Status code, Location (if redirected), Date* and *Server*.

What I'm doing is a simple axios GET request taking the input from the searchbar.
I'm trying to get my head around the CORS domain issues, but even then, when I input a CORS supported site like [myjson](https://myjson.dit.upm.es/about) I can access only the CORS-safelisted response headers which are not what I'm looking for.

This is the axios call:

```
axios
    .get(url)
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r);
      
      console.log(r.headers.server); //undefined
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

Is the brief I'm presenting even possible?

**UPDATE**

I've then tried removing the chrome extension I used to enable CORS requests and installed [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) extension. After restarting my PC I have now access to the remaining response headers.
I don't really know exactly what went wrong with the previous extension, but hopefully this helps somebody.

It's also worth pointing out that at the current date I'm writing this edit, myjson site has been flagged by chrome as non-safe for privacy issues. I've simply made HTTP requests to other sites and got the response headers as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response to a cross-origin request for https://myjson.dit.upm.es/about contains the CORS-related headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
```

but no [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers). Without that, a cross-origin client cannot access the `Server` header, because it is not CORS-safelisted.

It would work if you had your *server* make the request and evaluate the headers, not the `axios` *client*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Heiko. Can you suggest which topics I can look to make that request via server?

Comment: That depends on what software your server uses. Tags `node.js` and `express` are examples.